# Cryptic error message while parsing GPX file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing

In my previous question I asked about problem in a Python 3.5 program, that merged multiple gpx tracks into one klm file. I didn't receive answers for that and I decided to leave that bug as a optional feature.

Today, I completed GUI programming of my program and started to test using other (older) gpx files, I found from computers. While running program, this error message appears, but it doesn't break program work.

```
  ERROR:root:unbound prefix: line 14, column 0
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\gpxpy\parser.py", line 188, in parse
    self.xml_parser = XMLParser(self.xml)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\gpxpy\parser.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.dom = mod_minidom.parseString(xml)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\xml\dom\minidom.py", line 1968, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\xml\dom\expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 19, column 0
```

By trial and error I found out, that it is caused by `gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)`, which will raise `gpxpy.parser.mod_gpx.GPXXMLSyntaxException`. Since I used it as error exception, that error will return function and parent loop try to parse next file in list. GPX tracks, that cause exception, are skipped.

```
class funs: #Class for gruping custom functions
    #... Other functions
    def merg2(adr):
        try:
            gpx_file = open(adr, 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return
        try:
            gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file) #Raises error and returns
        except gpxpy.parser.mod_gpx.GPXXMLSyntaxException:
            return
        #... Process gpx
    #...
for i in o2: # o2 is list of files with full path
    infow(2) # GUI progress-bar updater
    try:
        funs.merg2(i) #Not merging. Just load tracks to graph
        exit() #Used for debugging only
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass    #Files may get damaged over time
```

I don't know what causes that error nor which lines in input files. Traceback occurs with each file, that can't be parsed, but line number in last line of message is sometimes different. It can be 14, 18, 19 or 22.

What does that error mean? What exactly causes that error? How can it be avoided? Should I edit gpx track, script or just ignore error?

PS. All GPX tracks I tried to import were generated by gpxpy module itself.

EDIT: Here's beginning of two gpx files. First original and then one generated by gpxpy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Locus Map, Android"
 xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd"
 xmlns:gpx_style="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2"
 xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
 xmlns:gpxtrkx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackStatsExtension/v1"
 xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v2"
 xmlns:locus="http://www.locusmap.eu">
    <metadata>
        <desc>File with points/tracks from Locus Map Pro/3.16.2</desc>
    </metadata>
<trk>
<name>2015-12-27.Lohusalus.jalutamas</name>
    <extensions>
        <gpx_style:line>
            <gpx_style:color>#960000FF</gpx_style:color>
            <gpx_style:width>4.0</gpx_style:width>
        </gpx_style:line>
    </extensions>
<trkseg>
```

Modified file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd" version="1.1" creator="Locus Map, Android">
<metadata>
<desc>File with points/tracks from Locus Map Pro/3.16.2</desc>
<author>
<link ></link></author>
<copyright ></copyright>
<link ></link></metadata>
<trk>
<name>2015-12-27.Lohusalus.jalutamas</name>
<desc> </desc>
<link ></link>
<extensions>
<gpx_style:line>
            </gpx_style:line></extensions>
<trkseg>
```

What could I do in order to prevent gpxpy `gpx.to_xml()` from defining line style?

Comment: Looks like a problem with unbound namespace prefixes in the gpx files. In your edit you show the element `gpx_style:line`. The namespace prefix `gpx_style` would need to be bound on the element or higher up in the xml tree (it would look something like `xmlns:gpx_style="some namespace uri"`) Can you confirm that `xmlns:gpx_style="???"` is not in the XML?

Comment: @DanielHaley `xmlns:gpx_style` was not in gpx file. I will edit post and add whole beginning of one file. Note, that these files were generated by gpxpy after running built-in track simplifier.